# MySQL Select Query when wanting groups of x elements returned in batches

Tags: mysql, database, select

How to return a select result with batches through a single query, that should be a straight forward compound select somehow. Below is a sample table and a simple query that will generate the desired result by currently using a temporary numeric column that could not work in the final real world process.

There are only two key columns involved: `ip addresses` and `oid addresses` for various SNMP items at that address. Need to have the returned results in groups of up to 10 items per ip address and then going to the next IP address and return up to 10 more and so on and when one pass through all the IP addresses is complete go back to the first IP and return the second group of up to 10, next IP and 10 and so on.

### Here is some sample data and simple query that somehow needs to be a compound query

### -- Table structure for table `test`

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `ip` varchar(16) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `oid` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `element` varchar(16) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `temp` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ip`,`oid`),
 KEY `element` (`element`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `test`

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES 
   ('1', '1.1.1', 'a', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.2', 'b', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.3', 'c', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.4', 'd', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.5', 'e', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.6', 'f', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.7', 'g', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.8', 'h', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.9', 'i', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.10', 'j', 1),
   ('1', '1.1.11', 'k', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.12', 'l', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.13', 'm', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.14', 'n', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.15', 'o', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.16', 'p', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.17', 'q', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.18', 'r', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.19', 's', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.20', 't', 5),
   ('1', '1.1.21', 'u', 9),
   ('1', '1.1.22', 'v', 9),
   ('1', '1.1.23', 'w', 9),
   ('1', '1.1.24', 'x', 9),
   ('1', '1.1.25', 'y', 9),
   ('1', '1.1.26', 'z', 9),
   ('2', '1.1.1', 'a', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.2', 'b', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.3', 'c', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.4', 'd', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.5', 'e', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.6', 'f', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.7', 'g', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.8', 'h', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.9', 'i', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.10', 'j', 2),
   ('2', '1.1.11', 'k', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.12', 'l', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.13', 'm', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.14', 'n', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.15', 'o', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.16', 'p', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.17', 'q', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.18', 'r', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.19', 's', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.20', 't', 6),
   ('2', '1.1.21', 'u', 10),
   ('2', '1.1.22', 'v', 10),
('2', '1.1.23', 'w', 10),
('2', '1.1.24', 'x', 10),
('2', '1.1.25', 'y', 10),
('2', '1.1.26', 'z', 10),
('3', '1.2.1', 'a', 3),
('3', '1.2.2', 'b', 3),
('3', '1.2.3', 'c', 3),
('3', '1.2.4', 'd', 3),
('3', '1.2.5', 'e', 3),
('3', '1.2.6', 'f', 3),
('3', '1.2.7', 'g', 3),
('3', '1.2.8', 'h', 3),
('3', '1.2.9', 'i', 3),
('3', '1.2.10', 'j', 3),
('3', '1.2.11', 'k', 7),
('3', '1.2.12', 'l', 7),
('3', '1.2.13', 'm', 7),
('3', '1.2.14', 'n', 7),
('3', '1.2.15', 'o', 7),
('3', '1.2.16', 'p', 7),
('3', '1.2.17', 'q', 7),
('3', '1.2.18', 'r', 7),
('3', '1.2.19', 's', 7),
('3', '1.2.20', 't', 7),
('3', '1.2.21', 'u', 11),
('3', '1.2.22', 'v', 11),
('3', '1.2.23', 'w', 11),
('3', '1.2.24', 'x', 11),
('3', '1.2.25', 'y', 11),
('3', '1.2.26', 'z', 11),
('4', '1.2.1', 'a', 4),
('4', '1.2.2', 'b', 4),
('4', '1.2.3', 'c', 4),
('4', '1.2.4', 'd', 4),
('4', '1.2.5', 'e', 4),
('4', '1.2.6', 'f', 4),
('4', '1.2.7', 'g', 4),
('4', '1.2.8', 'h', 4),
('4', '1.2.9', 'i', 4),
('4', '1.2.10', 'j', 4),
('4', '1.2.11', 'k', 8),
('4', '1.2.12', 'l', 8),
('4', '1.2.13', 'm', 8),
('4', '1.2.14', 'n', 8),
('4', '1.2.15', 'o', 8),
('4', '1.2.16', 'p', 8),
('4', '1.2.17', 'q', 8),
('4', '1.2.18', 'r', 8),
('4', '1.2.19', 's', 8),
('4', '1.2.20', 't', 8),
('4', '1.2.21', 'u', 12),
('4', '1.2.22', 'v', 12),
('4', '1.2.23', 'w', 12),
('4', '1.2.24', 'x', 12),
('4', '1.2.25', 'y', 12),
('4', '1.2.26', 'z', 12);
```

Query:

```
  SELECT `ip` , `oid` , `element`
    FROM `test`
ORDER BY `temp` ASC , `ip` ASC , `oid` ASC
   LIMIT 999
```

The following select query returns the desired result
now just need to figure out how to remove the temp column and create a select query that generates the same or similar result.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I'm not sure what your problem is, and format your code as such, it is difficult to read (and the db dump is not helpful)

Comment: @fredley: The db dump *is* helpful IMHO, and the question does make sense if you read it carefully.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your support and understanding and fredley I will work on the ways to format posts better in the future and a huge thank you to Abe Miessler for editing the post and reformatting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need to have the returned results in groups of up to 10 items per ip address and then going to the next IP address and return up to 10 more and so on and when one pass through all the IP addresses is complete go back to the first IP and return the second group of up to 10, next IP and 10 and so on.

MySQL unfortunately does not support the `ROW_NUMBER()` function that most other brands of database support, but you can simulate it with a user variable.

The following is tested with your data and MySQL 5.1.49:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SET @ip := null;

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT IF(@ip=ip,@rownum:=@rownum+1,@rownum:=0) AS rownum, @ip:=ip AS ip, oid
    FROM test ORDER BY ip, oid
) AS t
ORDER BY FLOOR(rownum/10), ip, oid;
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Thank you options would be a nice addition to Stack Overflow's arsenal.