# Selecting average over time with missing values

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve average values from mysql for the last logged 20 minutes entries (entries are logged every 10 seconds). The problem is that sometimes the data entries are missing e.g. minute 15-17 are not logged, and so I want the average to be for 22 minutes to give a correct average for the last logged 20 minutes intervals. Is there any way to write this in mysql, or will I need to program exceptions in my front end code?

```
SELECT *, avg(price) as avgprice20 
    FROM `shorttermprices` 
    where pricedatetime >= now() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE 
    ORDER BY `pricedatetime` DESC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Query when wanting groups of x elements returned in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517179/mysql-select-query-when-wanting-groups-of-x-elements-returned-in-batches)

Comment: Do you want to consider the missing entries as `= 0` ?

Comment: No - i need the time to be extended automatically if entries are missing. Another example is, that sunday from midnight to 0800 monday there are no entries, so monday morning at 0800 the average has to be extended at 08:01 with 8 hours or 8*60 minutes - the correct avg would then be now()-20+480 minute until 8:20

Answer (score 3):

Since you are logging data after every 10 seconds so in 20 minutes you will have 120 entries. So you could take the average of these 120 records.

```
SELECT avg(A.price) FROM (select * from shorttermprices order by pricedatetime desc limit 120) as A
```

This way it will adjust for missing records.

Comment: Since you know the period and the number of expected entries, you can condition with that.

Comment: Your query will always return only one row as you are using aggregate function in the same and don't have any group by field and no use of limit clause.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Updated the answer. Previously had copied the query straight from the OP Question.

Comment: Thank you - already thought of this, and it requires that data entry is always consistent with every 10 seconds, what if this is not consistent and also I need the time to be extended automatically if entries are missing. Another example is, that sunday from midnight to 0800 monday there are no entries, so monday morning at 0800 the average has to be extended at 08:01 with 8 hours or 8*60 minutes - the correct avg would then be now()-20+480 minute until 8:20

Comment: @PeterKroul This will be a more complex and might not be possible only with query. My response was actually based on your question where you stated that data is logged every 10 secs